# Efficiently representing sets of $n$-dimensional rectangles orthogonal an axis

Tags: cg.comp-geom

Is there a data structure that allows one to represent sets of $n$ dimensional rectangles, all orthogonal or parallel to the $x$ axis. efficiently. Allowing all common set operations (union, difference etc) to be done efficiently as well?

Let me explain what I mean by a 2D example.

Given this two set of rectangles `*` is the first set `%` is the second set

```
*************
*           *
*       %%%%o%%%%%%
*       %   *     %
********o ***     %
        %         %
        %%%%%%%%%%%
```

If I'll do `*` union `%`, I can get

```
*************
*           *
*******************
*                 *
*******************
        *         *
        ***********
```

or

```
*************
*           *
*******************
*       *   *     *
*******************
        *         *
        ***********
```

If I'll do `*` difference `%`, I can get

```
*************
*           *
*************
*       *
*********
```

Can you refer me to a relevant paper?

Comment: What does "supporting union" mean if you're maintaining a set of rectangles?  The union of two rectangles is not a rectangle.

Comment: Are your rectangles tilted in any which manner, or nice and orthogonal?

Comment: @ChadBrewbaker excellent question. None are tilted, all are orthogonal or parallel to the X axis.

Comment: @Chi-Lan could you clarify JeffE's question ? What is the desired output when you perform a union operation ?  or a difference ?

Comment: @JɛﬀE just a guess, but maybe he means set union of the sets of rectangles, where the rectangles in the set are allowed to overlap. BTW is an "n-dimensional rectangle" a box?

Comment: @SureshVenkat A set of rectangles orthogonal to the axis can remains a set rectangles after union or difference (you might have to split a rectangle into four rectangles, but it's still representable as a set of rectangles). I'll try to expand in the question.

Comment: This is a partial answer. R Tree(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_tree) supports some of the operations; insertion, deletion and search(does not support union etc). Seems to perform well in practice. I am unaware what theoretical guarantees it has.

Comment: Again, I'm still not sure exactly what you want.  Writing "data structure" suggests that you want to store a set of boxes and efficiently answer certain queries about that set and/or perform operations to modify that set.  Do you just mean "algorithm"?

Comment: Also: the union or difference of two n-dimensional boxes can be partitioned into at most 3n n-dimensional boxes in $O(n^2)$ time using the standard array representation $[min_1, max_1, min_2, max_2 \dots, min_n, max_n]$, by considering one dimension at a time.  Moreover, a partition of the union or difference of two n-dimensional boxes may require $\Omega(n)$ pieces, each represented by 2n numbers, so $O(n^2)$ time is worst-case optimal with that representation.  Do you want something better?

Comment: @JɛﬀE, I want a data structure, that will allow me to do the union difference and intersection as quickly as possible, and to find later if a certain point is contained in one of the rectangles. I want something that performs better, say. in the case that there are less than $O(n^2)$ boxes.

Comment: Let me try again.  What precisely should a union operation do to your data structure?  Do you mean "Given data structures representing two orthogonal polyhedra $X$ and $Y$, compute a data structure that represents the orthogonal polyhedron $X\cup Y$."?

Comment: @JɛﬀE, yes, and of course also $X\cap Y$, and $X\setminus Y$. Assuming that an orthogonal polyhedra is a polyhedra (not necessaryly connected) whose all edges are parallel of orthogonal to the `X` axis. (Thanks for trying, sorry I'm not clear enough).